# how to print float value upto 2 decimal place without rounding off

Tags: c

For example I want to print a value in c up to 2 decimal places, without rounding it off.

like:

```
a = 91.827345;
printf("%.2f", a);
```

will print `91.83`, but I want output to be `91.82` only. How to do it?

Comment: make a string, then print

Answer (score 3):

i'd suggest shorter and faster approach:

```
printf("%.2f", ((signed long)(fVal * 100) * 0.01f));
```

this way you won't overflow int, plus multiplication by 100 shouldn't influence the significand/mantissa itself, because the only thing that really is changing is exponent.

Comment: This does not work. Multiplication by 100 is lossy and introduces a rounding step. It also fails if `fVal` is greater than `INT_MAX/100`.

Answer (score 1):

The only easy way to do this is to use `snprintf` to print to a buffer that's long enough to hold the entire, exact value, then truncate it as a string. Something like:

```
char buf[2*(DBL_MANT_DIG + DBL_MAX_EXP)];
snprintf(buf, sizeof buf, "%.*f", (int)sizeof buf, x);
char *p = strchr(buf, '.'); // beware locale-specific radix char, though!
p[2+1] = 0;
puts(buf);
```

Comment: Oh! so my comment was correct :), Which file to include for `DBL_MANT_DIG`, and `DBL_MAX_EXP`? Why multiply by `2`?, Is it should be `buf[2*(DBL_MANT_DIG + DBL_MAX_EXP) + 1]` for nul-symbol ?

Comment: BTW that size bound is a little bit bigger than it needs to be, but not by orders of magnitude, unless you want to add a lot more logic. the smallest float really takes `DBL_MANT_DIG-DBL_MIN_EXP` (perhaps off-by-one) places after the decimal point to print exactly, but since the wanted number of places is two, you could short-circuit tiny values straight to `0.00` and only handle values greater than a fairly large threshold, reducing the number of places you need after the decimal to `DBL_MANT_DIG` plus a small constant.

Comment: @GrijeshChauhan: To address your edited comment: the factor of 2 is to have space for places both before and after the decimal point (in case the number is a huge integer). Actually a value of around 1.3 would work in place of 2 for that, but I was being lazy. The +1 is not needed since I already over-estimated; if it were, it would need to be a +2 anyway (for the radix).

Comment: Maybe you want `p[2+1] = 0`?